# Implementation of a UI using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I'm new to React JS and in general front-end.
I want to achieve a use case which is described as follows:

1. I have a bunch of conditional rules which are in form of drop-downs.
2. I can click on a "+" button to add new rules. I also have a "-" button to delete rules.
3. All these rules are connected by lines as shown in image link below.
4. The "+" button or "-" button is hidden by default and is shown when hovered.
5. Further details are given in image link provided below.

I am not able to think of how can i add these rules as drop-downs and connect them with lines.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[This is the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nefw1.png)

Comment: Question not showing any efforts made and this is opinion based question.

Comment: That's because I am new to front-end development and i don't know how to start this. Made efforts but all in vain

Comment: This is very advanced.  My recommendation would be to make an outline view of this first, maybe using simple HTML tags `ol` and `li`.  Once you get the adding and removing logic figured out, it will be easier to convert the outline to the version you are building.  Both representations appear to be trees.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be helpful. Will definately look into it.